# show a curve can be parametrized by any given interval

Tags: complex-analysis, curves

I'm working on a question of Lang's book Complex Analysis. Let $[a,b]$ an $[c,d]$ be two intervals, not reduced to a point. Show that there is a function $g(t)=rt+s$ such that $g$ is strictly increasing, $g(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$. Thus a curve can be parametrized by any given interval.

I was thinking that maybe $r>0$ for $g$ to be strictly increasing, but then $t>0$ has to be true as well. So now I'm stuck. Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to express $r$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$. You only need $r>0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown okay so I get $r=\frac{d-c}{b-a}$, thanks! I still don't see what to do next..

Comment: Is this $r$ positive?

Answer (score 0):

Let's be systematic. An affine function $g(t)=rt+s$ is strictly increasing iff $r\gt 0$ . (Indeed $g(t_1)-f(t_2)=r(t_1-t_2)$). Now we need $g(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$. This gives the system

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
ra +s=c\\
rb +s=d
\end{array}
\right.$$

Assuming $a\lt b$ and $c\lt d$, we have

$$r={d-c\over b-a}\gt 0$$

And $s=c-ra$. And we're done

Comment: ooh that's it already? okay great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to see how  this works is to think that the function $g(t)=rt+s$ is the equation of the segment that connect the points that have as coordinates the extremes of the two intervals (see the figure).

[image]

This equation, going from $A$ to $B$ is:

$$
y=g(t)=\frac{d-c}{b-a}(t-a)+c \qquad t\in[a,b]
$$